# Solr's MoreLikeThis feature: what's the benefit of using SearchComponent over MLT handler?

Tags: solr

By reading wiki, i am not clear on the differences (pros and cons) between using search component to add mlt and using MLT handler specifically. Can some expert here explain to me the differences, advantages and disadvantages? Thanks a lot! point me to a clear doc is ok too, since i cant find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is at the end of the [MoreLikeThis wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis#MoreLikeThisHandler):

> If you want to filter the similar results given by MoreLikeThis you
>   have to use the MoreLikeThisHandler. It will consider the similar
>   document result set as the main one so will apply the specified
>   filters (fq) on it. If you use the MoreLikeThisComponent and apply
>   query filters it will be applyed to the result set returned by the
>   main query (QueryComponent) and not to the one returned by the
>   MoreLikeThisComponent.

Comment: Thanks @javanna for pointing me to the doc! :) This is the advantage of using MoreLikeThisHandler. So besides of this, what's the advantage of using search component to do MLT? maybe it means that using MoreLikeThisHandler is always better than using search component?

Comment: Well, if you use the component you don't need to configure a specific handler, and it's already configured out of the box within the [SearchHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler)

Comment: Ah, I see...Hmm..but config a MLT handler isnt that much work either..Hmm...to summarize, if i wanna filter the MLT results, i'd better use MLT handler then. Thanks a lot for your help, javanna! :)

Comment: I run into a problem that I cannot use a float value field in the mlt.fl since a float is not a string. Then i also tried MLT handler with bq param but found that bq doesn't work with the handler. Then I researched a whole afternoon and found that I could use a search component to generate MLT queries then modify the query  by write my own component to get the results i really want...Maybe this is the right track, I will try it out. Hmmm...i am the solr newbie who is gonna write my first search component now..wish me good luck :( I will keep u posted

Comment: The 'mlt=true' component can also be thought of as 'more like these', because it can attach several 'like' documents to each of the main results (at corresponding cost).